# ¿Como solucionar Notice: Undefined index?

Tags: php, post, isset

que tal? estoy haciendo un formulario que envia los datos por post, pero me salta el error: 
"Notice: Undefined index", probe solucionarlos de dos maneras:

1.a las variables que cree le asigno el valor del name dentro del $_POST y luego lo compruebo con isset

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
     <head>
      <title></title>
    </head>
   <body>
     <form action="formulario.php" method="POST" name="formulario">
     Nombre:<input type="text" name="nombre">
     Pais:<input type="text" name="pais">
     <input type="submit" name="enviar" value="enviar">
    </form>

    <?php
      $nombre=$_POST["nombre"];
      $pais=$_POST["pais"];
      $enviar=$_POST["enviar"];
      $contador=0;

        if(isset($enviar)){
          if(isset($nombre) && isset($pais)){

            if($pais!="argentina" || $pais!="Argentina" || $pais!="ARGENTINA"){

               $contador++;

             echo "Paises distinto de Argentina:$contador";



              }

           echo "Nombre: $nombre <br> Pais:$pais";

                  }

                            }


                ?>
           </body>
            </html>
```

2.y aca decidi primero comprobar el $_POST con el valor del name pasado por corchetes y lo comparo con isset y sigue el mismo error

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
   <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <form action="formulario.php" method="POST" name="formulario">
   Nombre:<input type="text" name="nombre">
   Pais:<input type="text" name="pais">
   <input type="submit" name="enviar" value="enviar">
 </form>

 <?php
/*$nombre=$_POST["nombre"];
$pais=$_POST["pais"];
$enviar=$_POST["enviar"];*/
$contador=0;

 if(isset($_POST["enviar"])){

  $enviar=$_POST["enviar"];

if(isset($_POST["nombre"]) && isset($_POST["pais"])){
    $nombre=$_POST["nombre"];
    $enviar=$_POST["pais"];

    if($pais!="argentina" || $pais!="Argentina" || $pais!="ARGENTINA"){

        $contador++;

        echo "Paises distinto de Argentina:$contador";



    }

   echo "Nombre: $nombre <br> Pais:$pais";

 }

}


   ?>
    </body>
   </html>
```

esto es lo que sale:

Notice: Undefined index: nombre in C:\xampp\htdocs\post\formulario.php on line 2

Notice: Undefined index: pais in C:\xampp\htdocs\post\formulario.php on line 3

Notice: Undefined index: enviar in C:\xampp\htdocs\post\formulario.php on line 4

Comment: Primero que nada, así tienes tu documento en este momento o el PHP lo tienes dentro de otro documento aparte ?

Comment: todo en el mismo

Comment: Te falta el `id` en los inputs y el botón.

Comment: yo pense que el $_POST recibia entre los corchetes los name que le pongo en las etiquetas

Comment: entonces solo funciona con ids?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo único que tienes que hacer es primero realizar la comprobación de que exista tu elemento `$_POST["enviar"]` dentro de esta comprobación defines tus variables `$nombre` y `$pais`  el resto lo puedes dejar igual y quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="" method="POST" name="formulario">
    Nombre:<input type="text" name="nombre">
    Pais:<input type="text" name="pais">
    <input type="submit" name="enviar" value="enviar">
    </form>

    <?php
        if (isset($_POST['enviar'])) {
            $nombre=$_POST["nombre"];
            $pais=$_POST["pais"];
        }

        $contador=0;

        if(isset($nombre) && isset($pais)){
            if($pais!="argentina" || $pais!="Argentina" || $pais!="ARGENTINA"){
                $contador++;
                echo "Paises distinto de Argentina:$contador";
            }

            echo "Nombre: $nombre <br> Pais:$pais";

        }
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

por ultimo no se si la intención de tu código sea enviar dicha información a otro documento ya que si no lo es te recomiendo eliminar la propiedad `action` de tu `<form>`

Comment: al final lo puse en otro archivo aparte y lo llame en el formulario con el include, asi funciona graciass :D , Saludos!